# How to detect I/O in python source code(standard library way of I/O)

Tags: python, optimization, compiler-construction, io, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm build an optimizing compiler for a small subset of python code for my final year project. First thing I'm doing is testing whether a variable is involved in or leads to I/O. If I were to statically trace a function call down the proverbial rabbit hole, how exactly would I know that it involves I/O? Would there be a call to a built-in python function such as print, input, or built-in 'file' object function calls to read and write?

I don't have alot of time to do this project(only 6 months) so I'm completely ignoring people writing the I/O in C, wrapping it some sort of python object and calling it from python.

Is the byte code generated indicative of whether there's I/O? Or is it as unhelpful as the AST?

No biggie if it's undoable, I'll just my I/O subset for my project to print, input read and write. That or do liveness analysis.

Thanks.

Comment: It's inherently almost impossible to make these kinds of determinations with static analysis on a dynamically-typed language.  This is why it's so much harder to statically optimize dynamically-typed languages statically-typed ones.

Comment: @Glenn Don't worry about that. I can alter the subset of python I'm working with to be more or less restrictive. But my question still remains. What are the fundamental function calls for python I/O? Would they be the built-in function open("blah.txt", "rw").read and write? Or would it change depending on implementation(of say third party libraries)?

Answer (score 2):

It's not as simple as just looking at the bytecode because calls for things are just symbol lookups:

```
>>> def write_to_a_file(s):
    f = open('foo.txt', 'w')
    f.write(s)
    f.close()


>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(write_to_a_file)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (open)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo.txt')
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('w')
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (f)

  3          15 LOAD_FAST                1 (f)
             18 LOAD_ATTR                1 (write)
             21 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             27 POP_TOP             

  4          28 LOAD_FAST                1 (f)
             31 LOAD_ATTR                2 (close)
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             37 POP_TOP             
             38 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             41 RETURN_VALUE
```

The bytecodes them selves are just loading things, calling things, and storing things.  You'll actually have to look at the payload if you're operating at the bytecode level.

[Check out the current list of Python bytecodes](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#bytecodes) and you can see that there's really nothing there that distinguishes I/O calls.

Even if you were to inspect all `LOAD_GLOBAL` calls or `LOAD_FAST` calls and apply a whitelist, that wouldn't necessarily work because there are modules that provide I/O and the bytecode doesn't really help you there either:

```
>>> def uses_a_module_for_io(s):
    import shutil
    shutil.copy(s, 'foo.txt')


>>> dis.dis(uses_a_module_for_io)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (shutil)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (shutil)

  3          12 LOAD_FAST                1 (shutil)
             15 LOAD_ATTR                1 (copy)
             18 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
             21 LOAD_CONST               2 ('foo.txt')
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             27 POP_TOP             
             28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             31 RETURN_VALUE  

>>> def doesnt_use_shutil_really(s):
    shutil = object()
    shutil.copy = lambda x,y: None
    shutil.copy(s, 'foo.txt')


>>> dis.dis(doesnt_use_shutil_really)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (object)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (shutil)

  3           9 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <lambda> at 011D8AD0, file "<pyshell#29>", line 3>)
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             15 LOAD_FAST                1 (shutil)
             18 STORE_ATTR               1 (copy)

  4          21 LOAD_FAST                1 (shutil)
             24 LOAD_ATTR                1 (copy)
             27 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
             30 LOAD_CONST               2 ('foo.txt')
             33 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             36 POP_TOP             
             37 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             40 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that the `LOAD_FAST` for `shutil` can be something the user just makes up.  In my case I just made it a generic object, but the user can have a different `shutil` on their path as well.

Comment: In short: Python is a dynamic language, you can't do static analysis on it.